# for loop if the datetime object is greater than certain date

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to do a `for` loop with `datetime` object.
My idea is to loop over a list of item and exclude those outside 2 years range.
When I ran the following code, it didn't catch any error message.
However, it selected all the dates (within and outside 2 years range).

Code:

```
tday=pd.datetime.now().date()
two_yrs=tday - timedelta(730)
df['Gap End Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Gap End Date'])

gap=df['Gap End Date']
for i in gap:
    if i > two_yrs:
        df.to_csv('Downloads/Ene.csv', index=False)
print("The end")
```

Comment: NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined. Pls paste the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You're saving `df` to csv. That means you're saving your original data, without filtering older dates first.

This code snippet will subset your dataset to include only dates in the last two years:

```
tday=pd.datetime.now().date()
two_yrs=tday - timedelta(730)
df['Gap End Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Gap End Date'])

df_two_years = df[df['Gap End Date'>two_yrs]]
df_two_years.to_csv('Downloads/Ene.csv', index=False)

print("The end")
```